# Get all values in an object array with specific key (set::extract cakephp equivalent)

Tags: javascript

is there an equivalent of cakePHPs set::extract functionality (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::extract)?

What i've got is something like that:

```
var arr = [{name: "test", children: [id: 1, title: "title1"]},
           {name: "test2", children: [id: 2, title: "title2"]}, 
           {name: "lipsum", children: [id: 1, title: "title1", id: 2, title: "title2"]},
           {name: "lipsum2", children: [id: 3, title: "title3"]}]
```

What i want to do is:

```
var objs = filter({arr.children.id:1});
```

The result of 'objs' should be:

```
[{name: "test", children: [id: 1, title: "title1"]},
 {name: "lipsum", children: [id: 1, title: "title1", id: 2, title: "title2"]}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are **no associative arrays in Javascript**, only index-based, starting with 0.

Comment: Yep my fault...of course it should be an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid object structure... that children array should actually be an object. Then you can do:

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.children.filter(function(child) {
        return child.id === 1;
    }).length
});
```

Correct data format:

```
[{
    name: "test", 
    children: [{
        id: 1, 
        title: "title1"
    }]
}]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/588o5p69/

Comment: And assuming that `children` actually is an array of objects, you could also do `return (item.children || []).filter(child => child.id === 1)`

Comment: "that children array should actually be an object" - no, it should **not** be an object, but **an array of objects**.

Comment: The way you suggest it, it cannot represent `{name: "lipsum", children: [id: 1, title: "title1", id: 2, title: "title2"]}`

Comment: @connexo -- I've updated the answer to work with the `children` array.

Answer (score 0):

The correct structure for your array in JS would have to be this:

```
var arr = [{name: "test", children: [ {id: 1, title: "title1" } ]},
           {name: "test2", children: [ { id: 2, title: "title2" } ]}, 
           {name: "lipsum", children: [ {id: 1, title: "title1"}, {id: 2, title: "title2"}]},
           {name: "lipsum2", children: [ {id: 3, title: "title3"} ]}];
```

On that structure, you can simply use [underscore's `_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var resArr= _.filter(arr, function(elem){ return elem.children.id === 1; });
```

If IE < 9 is not relevant, you can also go with [ECMA Script 5's native filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var resArr= arr.filter(function(elem){ return elem.children.id === 1; });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). Even it is correct i prefer the native js functionality mentioned from tymeJV.

Comment: I can respect that. For future visitors, which answer would probably be best to be marked as the correct answer?